# Querying Cassandra columns with Pycassa

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

I have a Cassandra DB table similar to this:

```
key | name | client
1     A      C1
2     B      C2
3     C      C1
```

I access my Cassandra db with Python (Pycassa).

Is there a way to query the database in order to get the clients with the most number of occurrences? For instance, in this case it is `C1` with `2`.

I am not sure if it is possible to directly query Cassandra with Pycassa. If it is possible, how could I achieve that, or should I use other tools?

Thanks

PS:  I need to use nosql so please do not suggest me to use relational db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to separately keep track of the number of occurrences of each client.  If perfect accuracy isn't required, you can use Cassandra's built-in distributed counters.  Otherwise, you'll need to use a more accurate scheme (counting columns, periodic recounts, or both) or store a counter in a relational database.